# Files deleted using Linux still show up in Windows

Tags: windows-7, files, delete

I use Ubuntu and Windows 7 as dual boot.

I deleted a video from the Downloads folder in C drive while using my Ubuntu OS. I simply selected the video and did a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. When I switch to Windows, the file still shows up, although it gives an error while trying to open.

**What went wrong while deleting the file in Ubuntu?

Can I fix this and make the icon disappear in Windows using Ubuntu?**

Comment: Please clarify how you deleted the file and what filesystem you are using.

Comment: Seems to me a windows problem. file is on a c: drive=windows. file is visible on windows. file gives an error deleting it on windows. I doubt Ubuntu is the system to fix this from.

Comment: -> Use checkdsk from windows on the C drive

Comment: I think the video file really is deleted ("gives an error when trying to open" is a giveaway) but the shortcut to the file is still there, maybe in a recently used list or an app too. Delete or clear that.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a corrupted filesystem to me. Try `chkdsk` on Windows or `fsck` on Linux to check your file system and fix any possible corruption.

I don't think trash is the issue here. Both Ubuntu and Windows have this mechanism, with a similar concept – when “deleting” a file from the file manager, it is simply moved to a special folder instead of being deleted, and some metadata (original location and deletion date) is stored in a database. However, the implementations differ, so files moved to Trash under Ubuntu would not appear in the Windows Recycle Bin and vice versa. However, since files are moved, either way of deleting them will cause them to disappear from its original location.

Note that if you delete a file in another way than through the file manager, the trash folder may not be used and the file actually gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

They might still show up because they're in Ubuntu's trash bin. Try emptying your trash bin in Ubuntu with the C: disk mounted.

Comment: IF Ubuntu trashes a file on an external mounted file system, it creates a directory `.Trash-1000` (if your user ID is 1000) in the device's root directory. Inside that, it moves the trashed file to `files/` and some metadata (when it got trashed, where it was located) to `info/`, both files having the original file name.

Comment: -1 This is simply wrong. See the [other answer](/a/481806/175814) for an explanation.